# Unity3D - how to debug object instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene with a gameobject on it. By design there should only be one instance of this gameobject during the lifetime of the game. However, I get another instance of this gameobject created after I run the play mode. I'm pretty sure that my code does not create this second instance (there are no references to any of the components used on this gameobject, and I don't think I duplicate anything whatsoever) so there must be some package doing it.

I'm looking for an approach to debug who creates this instance. A way to see instantiation callstack would be perfect but I'm not sure if that is possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: One approach (probably not exactly the cleanest) would be to create a constructor with no arguments (if you don't already have one) in the object, then create a [`new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-6.0) within the constructor. You can then log this stack trace somewhere or view the value of it in the debugger to see what instantiated the class.

Comment: @Jesse The problem with this approach would be that Unity's gameobjects (MonoBehaviours actually) are not instantiated with constructors. Unity uses its own instantiation system.

Comment: All objects are instantiated by the constructor, including Unity ones I'm pretty sure. I've modded a handful of Unity games in my day and never had an issue with it not calling the constructor on objects that inherit MonoBehaviour.

Comment: @Jesse I must have expressed myself incorrectly. While it's true that objects are instantiated with constructor - in my case the stacktrace only contains the constructor (just double checked - 1 frame with ctor and that's it). I believe this is because of how Unity's instantiation system works.

Comment: Does this help? https://answers.unity.com/questions/27297/how-do-i-know-where-my-instantiated-object-came-fr.html

Comment: @Jesse it doesn't because all of the answers provided there presume the user having access to the instantiation code. In my case the instantiation is done by an external package, and if I knew the exact place where this was happening - I wouldn't have had the original question in the first place.

Comment: The first one doesn't. It's just adding a script to the object being instantiated

Comment: @Jesse this is not true. You need your parent object to set the origin: `localObject.GetComponent(scriptName).spawnOrigin = gameObject;`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before. A GameObject is spawning somewhere in a large project, you have no idea how. If you knew how it was being spawned, of course you could do the spawnOrigin trick. But that's the problem - you don't know the origin.

As @Jesse stated, all objects are instantiated with a constructor. So for the purposes of debugging, you can override a MonoBehaviour's constructor to give you some information.

```cs
public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour {
  public MyComponent() : base() {
    Debug.Log($"MyComponent: New GameObject instantiated");
  }
}
```

Note that the Unity Editor seems to call these constructors quite a bit, for reasons unknown to me. So I typically get the game to a state where I know the object is going to spawn, then add a breakpoint on my Debug.Log line, and wait for the breakpoint to be caught.

If you're unable to use a debugger, you can log a stack trace with every constructor:

```cs
Debug.Log(System.Environment.StackTrace);
```